# What is the diff between following declarations?

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<double> salaries();
vector<double> salaries;
```

I wanted to declare a empty vectors and above two declarations are possible as compiler returned no error. What is the difference between two above declarations?

Comment: If this is C or C++, then neither one of those are declarations (the first one is a function call, and the second is an expression statement with no side effects (likely to be considered dead code and eliminated by the optimizer).  Perhaps you need to explain your question a little better.

Answer (score 1):

With the update, the two declarations you show are:

1. vector<double> salaries(); // function named salaries that takes no parameters and returns a vector<double>
2. vector<double> salaries; // a variable with type vector<double> that is default-constructed

Note that (1) is sometimes written with the intention of doing the same thing as (2) (i.e. using the default constructor). But that's not how the compiler sees it - this is often referred to as a "most vexing parse", which you should be able to find much more information on with a little searching. Basically, though, it's an (intentional) ambiguity in the language syntax, that is resolved by the language specs by requiring that particular syntax to be treated as a function, but still surprises a lot of people.